# Create interactive metro map with pinch zoom (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, microsoft-metro, maps

I am quite new in Android and I got a really interesting project for an app. What I need is to create a metro map for two crossing metro lines/routes with their respective stations.

This seems easy at this point if we consider a static layout, with a background image for the metro routes and using buttons for the stations set in a relative way on the layout.

The hard part comes when the entire layout has to be zoomable, both for zoom buttons levels or pinch and zoom. This includes moving the map by drag after the zoom.

Maybe this question may be a bit confusing. If I haven't expressed myself well this is an example of an app which does more or less the same what I want:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtr.mtrmobile

This is a metro map of Hong Kong. I would like to create the same functionalities as the map on the App but in my case only for two metro lines.

I am not very familiar with android.graphics or OpenGL and I have been searching for a long time for answers or similar questions on internet without result.

I will be very grateful if anyone could explain me briefly how the map on the app was made or give me any idea on how I could achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you can have a look at OSMdroid, which will enable you to load offline maps, and you can overlay anything you want to.

Helpful:
https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

This works very similar to GoogleMaps API, so its pretty easy, and importantly you have moderators of the OSMdroid helping you all the way. I'm currently using this API, and i'm loving it.

Answer (score 1):

Like zIronManBox said, OpenStreetMap is a good way to go. By implemeting OSMdroid you can have online or offline maps and be able to add markers to location and even mark a whole street.

To get OSMdroid is also very easy. You will need to have two libraries:
**osmdroid-android-4.1.jar** and **slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar**. The versions are important.

Now you simply create an activty and an xml-file.

In your XML-file (the name of mine is map) you have this code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >


         <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/mapView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             tilesource="MAPQUESTOSM" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

This will create a view with the id mapView. If you want textfield above or below, you can add that in this XML-file.
In the activity you should add this code in your onCreate:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapController = (MapController) mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14);
```

Don't forget to add permissions in your manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you need good guides to get the map go work, visit 
http://android-er.blogspot.se/2012/05/simple-example-use-osmdroid-and-slf4j.html 
Here there are a lot of tutorials regarding OSMdroid!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example! I will try it later... Seems a good idea.. I guess I could use a custom overlay on top with my metro lines , use the coordinates to place station/button and polylines to mark the path between markers! Am I right?

Comment: I can't manage to go any further on this project. I acieved to use the maps noramlly but not ofline. I followed several tutorials and downloaded the write offline maps but can't manage to make it work. Can't neither overlay the image and buttons. Can you please give me more instructions on how to achieve all that? Your help would be much appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your response. Check my answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860792/osmdroid-offline-file/22794698#22794698) thread to get the map to work offline! @margabro